# Tool to discard packet payload?

Tags: linux, networking, pcap

I'm trying to anonymize packets from a pcap file that I have. I need to discard all the packets payloads/content (leaving only header information) and was wondering if there would be a tool that I could use for this (on Linux)? I have thought about using tcpdump with specifying the snaplen but with the header length changing, I don't think that would work.

If there isn't a tool that could accomplish this, a point in the direction of what library for coding would be best(easiest) would work as well. I'd rather not take that route since I have virtually no experience in network programming.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any network programming experience to anonymize the packets.  The format of the output file is well documented in the [pcap-savefile(5)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/pcap-savefile/) manpage.  You *will* need to lookup the layouts of the various protocols you'll be handling in order to identify what fields need to be anonymized.  You should also look at the [link layer header types](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) documentation at [tcpdump.org](http://tcpdump.org) to help you get started.

EDIT: Also look at libpcap itself... according to the pcap-savefile manpage:

> NOTE:  applications  and  libraries
>   should, if possible, use libpcap to
>          read savefiles, rather than having their own code  to  read 
>   savefiles.
>          If,  in the future, a new file format is supported by libpcap,
>   applica-
>          tions and libraries using libpcap to read savefiles  will  be 
>   able  to
>          read  the new format of savefiles, but applications and
>   libraries using
>          their own code to read savefiles will have to be changed to
>   support the
>          new file format.